# Getting the bounding box of a constant size item in Qt graphics views

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I need to get the bounding box (in scene space) of `QGraphicsItem`s that have the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag set.

According to the docs, you need to use [QGraphicsItem::deviceTransform()](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qgraphicsitem.html#deviceTransform) to do that. I tried this:

```
// Get the viewport => scene transform
vp_trans = view.viewportTransform();
// Get the item => viewport transform
trans = item.deviceTransform(vp_trans);
// Get the item's bounding box in item's space
bbox = item.boundingRect();
// Map it to viewport space
bbox = trans.mapRect(bbox);
// Map it back to scene's space
bbox = vp_trans.mapRect(bbox);
```

But something is wrong, the bounding boxes appear smaller and far to the right of the items...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out, QGraphicsView::viewportTransform() doc says "*Returns a matrix that maps viewport coordinates to scene coordinates*", but in fact it returns the **scene** to **viewport** transform.

Inverting vp_trans in the last step fixed my problem.

Comment: I ran into the same exact problem as you and this solved it.  Thanks a lot!